# Getting FunCaptcha token on Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, recaptcha, captcha

I want to load a funcaptcha via webview and give the token when the user solves that captcha.
url funcaptcha = https://fbsbx.com/captcha/recaptcha/iframe/

This code receives the Google Captcha token. How do I find the token of a FunCaptcha?

```
        binding.webview.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        binding.webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT)
        binding.webview.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url)

                binding.webview.loadUrl("javascript: if($('div.g-recaptcha').length)" +
                        "{" +
                        "var sitekey = $('div.g-recaptcha').attr('data-sitekey');" + // getting the site-key from existing recaptcha element
                        "$('body > *').remove(); " + // deleting all content of the page
                        "$('body').append('<div id=\"captcha\"></div>'); " + // a div to draw new recaptcha
                        "grecaptcha.render('captcha', {\n" + // render the new recaptcha element in 'captcha' div
                        "    'sitekey' : sitekey,\n" +
                        "    'callback' : function(response){console.log('captchatoken:'+response)},\n" + // log the token on callback
                        "});" +
                        "$('body').css('background-color','transparent');" + // for aesthetic purposes
                        "}");
                binding.webview.visibility = View.VISIBLE // show the WebView now since captcha is ready
            }
        }
        binding.webview.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage: ConsoleMessage): Boolean {
                val message = consoleMessage.message()
                binding.txtToken.text = message
                if (message.startsWith("captchatoken:")) {
                    val token = message.substring(13) // removing 'captchatoken:' part from console message

                    if (token.isEmpty()){
                        binding.txtToken.text = token
                        Log.d(TAG, "onConsoleMessage: ".plus(token))
                    }
                }
                return super.onConsoleMessage(consoleMessage)
            }
        }
        binding.webview.loadUrl("https://fbsbx.com/captcha/recaptcha/iframe/")
```